# It is this car. & It is that time to... & In those days the sky was a different colour

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you say there are correct/idiomatic sentences in these examples?
Also read my interpretations. Are they correct?

> It is this car. (for example, we have found it)
>
> It is that time to speak English. (for example, we have free time and possibility right now)
>
> In those days the sky was a different colour. (for example, in the past my life was better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and last ones sound fine, and your interpretations for them (given some context) are also good. The middle one sounds strange. The use of the word "that" is... weird.

More natural ways to say the second sentence are below. The first sounds the most natural to me:

- It is time to speak English. (just get rid of "that")
- This is the time to speak English.
- Now is the time to speak English.

If you really wanted to incorporate "that" into the phrase, I'd break it up into 2 sentences and go with: "It's that time again! It's time to speak English."

Answer (score 1):

The first and third are fine. They are correct. Each says what you want it to say, given sufficient context.

The second one sounds off. I would say

> Now is the (or a)  time to speak English.

or

> That is the (or a) time to speak English.